# Unable to run huggingface transformers in python3 | ssl.SSLCertVerificationError

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run the transformers package from huggingface for text generation in python 3.8.2 on my company laptop.

The code is as follows:

```
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
```

But I am getting this SSL certificate error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 416, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python382\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Python382\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python382\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\mss\Work\RI_Demo\myvenv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gpt2/resolve/main/config.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you run it inside the vpn of your company ?

Comment: Yes inside VPN.

Comment: then ist just blocket.. it happend to me a lot. If its for a Work project you would need to ask your IT-helpdesk about to open the port=443 for you ip

Comment: I tried accessing the url from browser, it is working fine